# Google CodeJam 2016 - Ruby - Counting Sheep

Tags: ruby, array

I just wrote a small Ruby class to solve the first of the challenges in the G CodeJam. I am not strong at this sort thing so very sure it can be simplified massively! The program is correct for both the small and large inputs.

[Challenge](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard#s=p0&a=0)

> Problem
>
> Bleatrix Trotter the sheep has devised a strategy that helps her fall
>   asleep faster. First, she picks a number N. Then she starts naming N,
>   2 × N, 3 × N, and so on. Whenever she names a number, she thinks about
>   all of the digits in that number. She keeps track of which digits (0,
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9) she has seen at least once so far as
>   part of any number she has named. Once she has seen each of the ten
>   digits at least once, she will fall asleep.
>
> Bleatrix must start with N and must always name (i + 1) × N directly
>   after i × N. For example, suppose that Bleatrix picks N = 1692. She
>   would count as follows:
>
> N = 1692. Now she has seen the digits 1, 2, 6, and 9. 2N = 3384. Now
>   she has seen the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, and 9. 3N = 5076. Now she
>   has seen all ten digits, and falls asleep. What is the last number
>   that she will name before falling asleep? If she will count forever,
>   print INSOMNIA instead.
>
> Input
>
> The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test
>   cases follow. Each consists of one line with a single integer N, the
>   number Bleatrix has chosen.
>
> Output
>
> For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is
>   the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the last number that
>   Bleatrix will name before falling asleep, according to the rules
>   described in the statement.

```
class CountingSheep
  def solve(input)
    return "INSOMNIA" if input == 0
    current = input
    seen_numbers = []

    loop do
      seen_numbers.concat(current.to_s.split(//))
      break if seen_numbers.uniq.size == 10
      current += input
    end
    current
  end

  def get_inputs(data_size)
    array = []
    path = "~/Desktop/counting_sheep/A-#{data_size}-practice.in"

    File.open(File.expand_path(path), 'rb') do |f|
      f.each_line do |line|
        array << line.strip
      end
    end
    array.shift
    array
  end

  #'small' or 'large' data_size input
  def output(data_size: "small")
    count = 1
    get_inputs(data_size).each do |input|
      output = solve(input.to_i)
      puts "Case ##{count}: #{output}"
      count += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Habit I guess. You are of course right - it's definitely not needed.

Answer (score 1):

In no particular order:

- I'd prefer `.zero?` rather than `== 0`
- You could use a hash instead of an array and remove the need to call `uniq`. That method quickly gets pretty expensive, especially since you're calling it on an ever-growing array
- I'd like the `solve` method to return either an integer or `nil`, instead of mixing string and number return types.

As for getting digits from a number, I'd suggest using `#divmod`. Coverting to a string and splitting always irks me a little, even if it is a pretty straightforward solution. But like the return type from `solve`, I see no reason to involve strings when trying to get numbers from a number.

Basically, you can do something like this:

```
require 'set'

def unique_digits(number)
  digits = Set.new
  remainder = number
  while remainder > 0
    remainder, digit = remainder.divmod(10)
    digits << digit
  end
  digits
end
```

This is using a `Set` (part of the stdlib) since it guarantees uniqueness - no need to call `uniq` on an array.

As for the core of the task:

```
def count_sheep(n)
  return nil if n.zero?
  digits = Set.new
  current = 0
  while digits.size < 10
    current += n
    digits += unique_digits(current)
  end
  current
end
```

All you need then is the method to run it. I'd suggest something like:

```
def read_input(io)
  cases = io.gets.strip.to_i
  cases.times do |i|
    n = io.gets.strip.to_i
    puts "Case ##{i+1}: #{count_sheep(n) || "INSOMNIA"}"
  end
end
```

Where `io` is a file handle or stdin. That way you can run your script in two ways; piping things to stdin, or reading from a file. All it needs is an `IO` object. E.g.:

```
read_input(ARGV[0] ? File.open(ARGV[0]) : STDIN)
```

should let run either `$ ruby sheep.rb <file>` or `$ cat <file> | ruby sheep.rb`

---

In all:

```
require 'set'

def unique_digits(number)
  digits = Set.new
  remainder = number
  while remainder > 0
    remainder, digit = remainder.divmod(10)
    digits << digit
  end
  digits
end

def count_sheep(n)
  return nil if n.zero?
  digits = Set.new
  current = 0
  while digits.size < 10
    current += n
    digits += unique_digits(current)
  end
  current
end

def read_input(io)
  cases = io.gets.strip.to_i
  cases.times do |i|
    n = io.gets.strip.to_i
    puts "Case ##{i+1}: #{count_sheep(n) || "INSOMNIA"}"
  end
end

read_input(ARGV[0] ? File.open(ARGV[0]) : STDIN)
```